# SingleChildScrollView on overall body

Tags: flutter

I want to wrap the body inside a SingleChildScrollView widget but for some reason, it is not working. When I wrap the Container inside a SingleChildScrollView widget everything goes away. Any solution?

```
Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Spacer(),
            DisplayText(),
            Spacer(),
            Form(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Enter your username',
                    ),
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Enter your password',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            .
            .
            .
            .

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the entire layout with `Column` and expand the child using `Expanded` widget then add `SingleChildScrollView`. Please remove `Spacer`, if you need space in-between widgets use `SizedBox` instead.

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    DisplayText(),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    Form(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'Enter your username',
                            ),
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'Enter your password',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Your idea works fine. But I have a question, why not use Spacer() ?